# PJSIP Hangup RTP Timeout

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

Is there any alternative of `RTP` Timeout in `PJSIP` ? Please let me know because i want to Hangup video call from device when internet connection is lost.

Comment: Did you try with pjsua_destroy(); safely and re-create fresh session.

Comment: Without internet how?

Comment: UI will block for 6 seconds... 3 seconds for pjsua_destroy() and 3 seconds for re-create fresh session. @Sakshi

Comment: what if you dismiss Controller in which video call is happening and on other side keep flag when internet comes resume session.

Comment: check internet reachability with reachabilty class. if network mode is disconnected just dismiss your viewcontroller of video call.